# Alternative way to integrate JavaFX with a Stomp Websocket Client, preferably Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javafx, websocket

I am developing a JavaFX application (Gradle, Intellij) that performs some operations remotely by connecting to an application server via WebSocket. The server is developed using Spring Boot and implemented as a STOMP WebSocket. The client part shall be somehow integrated into the existing JavaFX application.
The integration of JavaFX and Spring Boot has good documentation. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147076/how-to-use-spring-with-javafx) on Stackoverflow is not too recent, but there is this post on [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/16/spring-tips-javafx), but also some other material based on the same idea like: [samydavic blog](https://medium.com/@samydavic/javafx-application-with-spring-boot-2b7c3374e675), this [project on GitHub](https://github.com/trishagee/s1p-stocks-ui) and [this post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/11/tutorial-reactive-spring-boot-a-javafx-spring-boot-application/) from the same person. The solution presented is very elegant but actually changes the JavaFX application to a Spring Boot application and looks too complex for the kind of application I am developing, which basically sends a json object to the server and receives another one as response. There are some useful tools like [FxWeaver](https://rgielen.net/posts/2019/creating-a-spring-boot-javafx-application-with-fxweaver/), [spring-boot-starter-javafx](https://github.com/yoep/spring-boot-starter-javafx) but again, the are additional dependencies and more stuff to handle.

My question is: what alternative solution can be recommended (if any) to let my existing JavaFX application to have a simple stomp websocket client added?

An option which I am considering is to have a Spring Boot websocket client and to have it connected to the JavaFX application via a socket over TCP (since they will both run on the same machine) which is very easy to implement; the websocket client would work as a message broker for JavaFx application.

Answer (score 2):

This is subjective, so it is an opinion, there is not really a right or wrong answer.

You don't need 3rd party things like fxweaver, spring-boot-starter-javafx if you don't want them. You can integrate [JavaFX and spring boot directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887944/adding-spring-dependency-injection-in-javafx-jpa-repo-service/57896435#57896435). Once that is done you can use the appropriate starter projects from spring boot as [dependencies](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) to add the functionality you need.

If you just want to use raw web sockets, you don't need spring at all, as the functionality for [websocket clients is in the JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html).

Working with native web sockets seems simple but can be trickier than you expect because it is a low-level system without a defined protocol for messaging. If you do want to use stomp over websockets instead, it [may not be overly complex](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-api-java-spring-client), though there is a learning curve either way.

Comment: Indeed this is a subjective answer and quite open, but good to know ideas from the community. Thanks for pointing to [how to integrate JavaFX and Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887944/adding-spring-dependency-injection-in-javafx-jpa-repo-service/57896435#57896435), gives a very good hint. Interesting is the concept of "separation of concerns" which in my case makes lot of sense because I will probably not make a massive use of Spring and the idea of have it somehow separate from the GUI is interesting. Also [Gluon Ignite](https://gluonhq.com/labs/ignite/) is worth considering

Comment: I can't help but feel that any attempt to merge JavaFX with Spring or Websockets is wrong-headed.  Your API/Websocket stuff should be implemented in as a Service that's called from your JavaFX business logic - which should be the Model (or some equivalent).  The Model deals with integrating the Domain Object data to/from the Presentation Data.  

Take a look at this article I wrote:  https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/weather

Comment: Thanks DaveB, the article and the sample code are very interesting. I share your view and would prefer to have JavaFX decoupled from the service. What I am interested is to have the simplest solution, if I can achieve that integrating JavaFX with Spring, I would go with that. Gluon Ignite looks promising

Comment: Testing Gluon Ignite, maybe somebody can help with this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75561231/javafx-app-integrated-with-spring-boot-and-gluon-ignite-does-not-load-fx-runtime)